# Haskell Maybe/Parametric Polymorphism

Tags: haskell

I have this code :

```
getLengthOfMissingArray :: Maybe [Maybe [Int]] -> Maybe Int 
getLengthOfMissingArray maybelist = do
  ns <- maybelist 
  getMissing ns

getMissing :: [Maybe [Int]] -> Maybe Int 
getMissing maybelist
  | any (==Nothing) maybelist = Nothing
  | any (==Just []) maybelist = Nothing
  | otherwise                 = Just (sumn mx - sumn (mn - 1) - sum l0)
  where
    l0 = map length (catMaybes maybelist)
    (mn,mx) = (minimum l0, maximum l0)
    sumn n = n * (n + 1) `quot` 2
```

Which is a Haskell translation of this :

https://www.codewars.com/kata/length-of-missing-array

Now it works, however I have two issues :

- it is kind of fugly
- it should work on any list, not just int's

I would like to have getMissing just be :

```
getMissing :: [[Int]] -> Int
```

And then just use that function inside of the other one, but I don't know how to utilize that function on the `Maybe` of a `Maybe`.

Second, I tried simply doing :

```
getMissing :: Eq a => [Maybe [a]] -> Maybe Int 
getLengthOfMissingArray :: Eq a => Maybe [Maybe [a]] -> Maybe Int
```

But then Haskell generates errors when I try to use QuickCheck on test cases like :

```
getLengthOfMissingArray (Just [ Nothing, Just [ 4, 5, 1, 1 ], Just [ 1 ],
                                Just [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] ])     `shouldBe` Nothing
```

That works, but this generates type errors :

```
getLengthOfMissingArray (Just [Just []])                      `shouldBe` Nothing
```

I guess without an actual `a` there there's an issue because if I just try to run it on a `Nothing` it also generates the same type error:

> "Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘getLengthOfMissingArray’
>         prevents the constraint ‘(Eq a0)’ from being solved."

Comment: Note that `getMissing` doesn't really need to have `Maybe Int` as its return type; you are always getting *some* list as input, so you can always return at least 0. You'll do some additional filtering in the body, but the end result is that you can them simply define `getLengthOfMissingArray = fmap getMissing`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sequence :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]` will help you adapt your `[Maybe [Int]]` to `[[Int]]`.

`join :: Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a` might also be useful.

Both [sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequence) and [join](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) have more general types - I wrote them as I expect you will use them here.

You will see "Ambiguous type variable" errors when you pass a polymorphic value to a function that is polymorphic in its argument.  To actually run the function GHC needs to use a specific type, and it won't choose - you need to.  Since you want `getLengthOfMissingArray` to remain polymorphic, you can add a type signature to the test case to specify how the tests should run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bergey (and dramforever on cw) :

```
getLengthOfMissingArray :: Eq a => Maybe [Maybe [a]] -> Maybe Int 
getLengthOfMissingArray maybelist = do
  list  <- maybelist 
  ns    <- sequence list 
  getMissing ns

getMissing :: Eq a => [[a]] -> Maybe Int 
getMissing list
  | any (==0) l0  = Nothing
  | otherwise     = Just $ sumn mx - sumn (mn - 1) - sum l0
  where
    l0 = map length list
    (mn,mx) = (minimum l0, maximum l0)
    sumn n = n * (n + 1) `quot` 2
```

And adjusting the tests :

```
getLengthOfMissingArray (Nothing :: Maybe [Maybe [Int]]) `shouldBe` Nothing
```